# AS2: setInterval is only called once

Tags: actionscript

I have the following function and interval, it is called once but then never again. Can anyone see why?

```
    function tweenArrow() {
        trace("called");
        var TweenAX:Tween = new Tween(circle.current.arrowHead, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle.current._x, Stage.width/2, 2, true);
        var TweenAY:Tween = new Tween(circle.current.arrowHead, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle.current._y, Stage.height/2, 2, true);
    }
    setInterval(tweenArrow(),2000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling your function instead of giving a reference to `setInterval`. Try

```
setInterval(tweenArrow,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

While calling a function, use the function name without (). [Here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/setinterval/) is an example tutorial for this method.